# Como efetuar Dump Mysql linha do comando sem as Views

Tags: mysql, dump

Alguém sabe como efetuar um dump de uma base de dados no MySql via linha de comando sem as views, somente as tabelas da base de dados?

Comment: O que seria "views" que você se refere ?

Comment: Uma View é um objeto que pertence a um banco de dados, definida baseada em declarações SELECT´s, retornando uma determinada visualização de dados de uma ou mais tabelas.